# Set prefix key on load of minor mode

Tags: hooks, minor-mode

I am trying to change the default prefix key <kbd>C-c @</kbd> to <kbd>C-c</kbd> for `outline-minor-mode`:

```
      (define-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c")
        (lookup-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c @")))
```

This works fine if `outline-minor-mode` is already loaded. But I cannot find a way to put this into `.emacs` so that it is run whenever `outline-minor-mode` is activated.

I have tried:

```
(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook
      (define-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c")
        (lookup-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c @"))))
```

Which gives:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: outline-minor-mode-map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass a *function* to `add-hook`.  As it is you are evaluating the `define-key` call immediately, which is why you get the error.

`with-eval-after-load` is exactly what you are looking for.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "outline"
  (define-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c")
              (lookup-key outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c @"))))
```